# TImage losing loaded picture

Tags: delphi, png, image, timage

Running Turbo Delphi Pro.

I'm using TImage to display a png image.

When I restart Delphi and load the dpr file, TImage is still there, but the picture is lost,
requiring a reload of the picture before compiling.

At first I thought it's a path issue, so I loaded the picture from the same directory as the dpr, but it didn't help.

What else can I try?

Comment: I did not think that Turbo Editions had support for PNG I thought that was added after the Turbo Editions.

Comment: @Robert Love. Turbo Pro has PNG.  I tried it with a JPEG, and it kept the picture.

Comment: In my D2007 there's no built-in PNG support (only "PNG graphics from DevExpress"). I guess that's no different in D2006/Turbo.

Comment: PNG <> JPEG, Delphi has had support JPEG for years but I thought that PNG was added in later version of Delphi.    Try loading the picture at runtime if that works then PNG support is in Turbo.

Comment: Maybe your DFM is read-only? Not likely since the TImage "sticks", but who knows? If all else fails maybe you can copy-paste the contents of the dfm file after the PNG is loaded.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

- Open your project and your  Form with
  the PNG.
- (Re)Load the PNG image.
- Save and close your Form.
- With a text editor, load your Form
  DFM
- **I bet you don't have a big binary in
  your TImage object**, because the PNG content
  has not been saved.

Bottom line, you'd have to **include it as a resource and load it dynamically at runtime.**

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem as well with D2006.  The solution I used is similar to François'.

I have a TPngImageCollection component that I collect all the images in at design time.  You will need to find unit PngImageList off the web.  The TPngImageCollection component has the advantage that you can have a collection of PNG images of differing sizes.

At run-time on startup, I assign the TImages from each of the collection members:

```
Image1.Picture.Assign (ImageCollection.Items [0].PNGImage) ;
Image2.Picture.Assign (ImageCollection.Items [1].PNGImage) ;
Image3.Picture.Assign (ImageCollection.Items [2].PNGImage) ;
etc
```

Bingo - you can produce your PNG originals with alpha transparency (I use PhotoPlus 6.0 from Serif - free and very capable) and show them in a TImage.